# Internal error at Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried running my query several times, but I am getting internal errors. Some jobs ids:

- tag-bd-153719:bquijob_5b4f1f1f_159c05bcd23 (internal error)
- tag-bd-153719:bquijob_16b688af_159be147be4 (resources exceeded -- once on smaller dataset I got this error, all other query runs just worked; what tier do I need?)
- tag-bd-153719:bquijob_3cc7f914_159bdcf0fa8 (internal error)
- tag-bd-153719:bquijob_75ac655a_159bdc3e494 (internal error)

What's the cause? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Per https://status.cloud.google.com/ there was an issue with table copy and small percentage of queries in BigQuery, but now it is all resolved. Latest update says:

> The issue with BigQuery's Table Copy service and query jobs should
>   have been resolved for all affected projects as of 07:30 US/Pacific.
>   We will conduct an internal investigation of this issue and make
>   appropriate improvements to our systems to prevent or minimize future
>   recurrence

Comment: Thanks! It stopped crashing.